# How to install The Sleuth Kit if "configure" file is missing?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, forensics

I tried installing from source on macOS. The repo does not have a `configure` file, so I cannot run

```
$ ./configure
```

as mentioned in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/blob/develop/INSTALL.txt).

The repo has a `configure.ac`, so following [this advice](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-run-a-configure-ac-file-4175596216/), I first ran `autoconf` and `automake`, then:

```
$ ./configure
configure: error: cannot find required auxiliary files: config.guess config.sub install-sh
```

I also tried the different order, `automake` and `autoconf`, and I get the same error.

How can I install TSK from source on macOS?

Comment: Try the step-by-step instructions at https://cybersocialhub.com/csh/installing-autopsy-on-macos-big-sur-arcpoint/, which includes directions for configuration.

Comment: Have you try to use `ports`? Do you really need to compile from source?